# File.listFiles() returns null on a mapped network drive

Tags: java, network-drive, eclipse-luna

Eclipse Luna doesn't see the mapped Network drives!
Obviously I am able to read any file on the mapped drive.

Here is my test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws       
    // this part works properly
    File myFile = new File("C:\\test.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myFile);
    fw.write("test");
    fw.close();

    //this will throw an exception
    myFile = new File("O:\\");
    File[] myList = myFile.listFiles();
    System.out.println(myList.length);
}
```

running as a Java application I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at variousTest.fileFinder.main(fileFinder.java:28)
```

I can confirm you that the drive has a big list of folder inside it.

Operating System: Windows 7 Professional SP1

**UPDATE I - 10 September:**

i tried to run the program outside eclipse, and it i am bewildered about the result, in fact i got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.FileNotFoundException: C:\test.txt (Access Denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
at fileFinder.main(fileFinder.java:14)
```

**UPDATE II - 10 September:**

above exception (update I) was raised becouse of rights. The program runs correctly using the directory **C:\Users\username\Desktop**

Comment: Run it from a command line, first trying `O:` and `dir`. This should take care of authorization being done for the Windows user. Then listFiles should no longer return null. (No solution, but to see whether this helps.)

Comment: @greg-449 Line 28 is the SystemOut.

Comment: @JoopEggen "dir O:" return the full list of folder inside the O: drive in the command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Windows usually requires administrator rights to access the root of `C:`. Can you try writing to your Desktop folder? The path would then be `C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\test.txt`.

Comment: It **works**. 
Thank you.
Any suggestion to the main problem?

Comment: Do you have `O:\` in your Windows Explorer? Can you access it from Windows Explorer and do you see the files you expect to see?

Comment: Yes, it is mapped as O: and i can see it in window explorer inside the network path section.
As written above, i can either double click to see file, either use the command "dir O:" in the prompt to see the file List

Comment: Can you try `myFile = new File("\\\\server\\path\\to\\share");` to see if you can access it that way? From the Javadoc: `Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.`

Comment: using the full name it **works**, but the project have to be deployed on the server itself, and i cannot change that line. My old laptop (i changed it last week) was able to read from the server using that denotation

Comment: Has anything changed in the configuration of the share? Did you maybe use other credentials when you mapped your network drive? Also, does the user that executes the code have that network drive mapped?

Comment: The Domain itself is changed, and also my previously IDE version was the Kepler.
Yes, i have the network drive mapped, and I can access them by double-clicking on the drive shown in the computer explorer window

Comment: In that case, I would contact your domain administrator and see if he/she can make that share accessible for everyone (no credentials needed). You can also try Kepler again and see if that works (I doubt it, but it's worth a try).